# How can I get v-flex to use fill height correctly in this scenario?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm attempting to use fill-height for a v-flex but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure what I'm missing.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/ccasad/pen/MMEORo

I'd like the bottom of purple box to line up with bottom of orange box and the bottom of cyan box to line up with bottom of orange box.

```
  <v-container fluid grid-list-lg text-xs-center>

    <v-layout row wrap>

      <v-flex d-flex xs6 style="background-color:green;">
          Top left
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex d-flex xs6 style="background-color:blue;">
          Top right
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex d-flex xs3 fill-height style="background-color:purple;">
          Bottom left
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex d-flex xs6 style="background-color:tan;">
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex d-flex xs12 style="background-color:yellow;">
              Bottom middle top<br>more text
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex d-flex xs12 style="background-color:red;">
              Bottom middle middle<br>more text
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex d-flex xs12 style="background-color:orange;">
              Bottom middle bottom<br>more text
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex d-flex xs3 fill-height style="background-color:cyan;">
          Bottom right
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

  </v-container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `fill-height` property from the purple and cyan `v-flex` elements.

PS - `v-flex` doesn't have a `fill-height` property

PPS - `v-flex` also doesn't have a `d-flex` property so drop that too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but you can replace v-flex with div and set a style for it with display:flex

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">    
  <v-container fluid grid-list-lg text-xs-center>        
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex d-flex xs6 style="background-color:green;">
          Top left
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex d-flex xs6 style="background-color:blue;">
          Top right
      </v-flex>
      <div xs3 fill-height style="background-color:purple;display:flex;align-items:stretch;align-contents:stretch;flex-grow:1;">
          Bottom left
      </div>
      <v-flex d-flex xs6 style="background-color:tan;">
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex d-flex xs12 style="background-color:yellow;">
              Bottom middle top<br>more text
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex d-flex xs12 style="background-color:red;">
              Bottom middle middle<br>more text
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex d-flex xs12 style="background-color:orange;">
              Bottom middle bottom<br>more text
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
      <div xs3 fill-height style="background-color:cyan;display:flex;align-items:stretch;align-contents:stretch;flex-grow:1;">
          Bottom right
      </div>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
```